# How do I loop through results from std::regex_search?

Tags: c++, regex, stl, c++11

After calling `std::regex_search`, I'm only able to get the first string result from the `std::smatch` for some reason:

```
Expression.assign("rel=\"nofollow\">(.*?)</a>");
if (std::regex_search(Tables, Match, Expression))
{
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < Match.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << Match[i].str() << std::endl;
}
```

So I tried to do it another way - with an iterator:

```
const std::sregex_token_iterator End;
Expression.assign("rel=\"nofollow\">(.*?)</a>");
for (std::sregex_token_iterator i(Tables.begin(), Tables.end(), Expression); i != End; ++i)
{
    std::cout << *i << std::endl;
}
```

This does go through every match, but it also gives me the whole matching string instead of just the capture that I was after. Surely must be another way than having to do another `std::regex_search` on the iterator element in the loop?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`regex_token_iterator` takes an optional fourth argument specifying which submatch is returned for each iteration. The default value of this argument is 0, which in case of the C++ (and many other) regexes means "the whole match". If you want to get the first captured submatch, simply pass 1 to the constructor:

```
const std::sregex_token_iterator End;
Expression.assign("rel=\"nofollow\">(.*?)</a>");
for (std::sregex_token_iterator i(Tables.begin(), Tables.end(), Expression, 1); i != End; ++i)
{
    std::cout << *i << std::endl; // *i only yields the captured part
}
```

Comment: This needs more `for (auto it : ...)`.

Comment: @rr-, the foreach loop can be used in situations where the corresponding iterator loop would have the form `for(auto i = begin(container); i != end(container); ++i)`. This is not one of those cases.

Comment: You're right, of course, and I didn't mean to criticize your answer in any way. It's just an observation that comes from seeing how people create (nonstandard) stuff that lets you write code such as `for (auto i : range(10))`. I believe having such adapters for regex would make them more readable, and I think it's possible with some boost adapters. I certainly wouldn't complain if they were incorporated into stdlib at some point.

Comment: @rr- Ah, right. Yeah, a "regex_range" wrapper would certainly make the loop look cleaner.

Comment: Should it not be `const std::sregex_token_iterator End;` in the first line? Otherwise I get `error: no match for ‘operator!=’`

Answer (score 6):

`std::regex_search` searches for the regex just once. It does not return a list of matches, but a list of submatched expressions (those within parentheses). This is why you only get one `Match[1]`, the text inside the link tag.

As for the second code, it actually returns you all the matches, but it returns you again `match_results` object, so you have to use the `[]` operator:

```
const std::sregex_iterator End;
Expression.assign("rel=\"nofollow\">(.*?)</a>");
for (std::sregex_iterator i(Tables.begin(), Tables.end(), Expression); i != End; ++i)
{
    std::cout << (*i)[1] << std::endl; // first submatch, same as above.
}
```

Comment: I see. Is there a way around calling regex_search in the iterating loop?

Comment: Yes, I added the modification to the second code of yours that actually prints the first submatch.

Comment: @Diego, @Nop: `regex_token_iterator` actually only returns a single submatch per iteration; Diego's code would be correct if it used `regex_iterator` instead. See my answer for details.

Comment: Thanks, JohannesD. Corrected!