# C++ regex not understanding

Tags: c++, regex

The following outputs ">Hut" where I expect it to output "Hut". I know that .* is greedy but > must be matched and it is outside of the capture group so why is it in my submatch?

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        regex my_r(".*>(.*)");
        string temp(R"~(cols="64">Hut)~");
        smatch m;
        if (regex_match(temp, m, my_r)) {
                cout << m[1] << endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: note that regex implementation support is still very low on gcc and MSVC probably, too.

Comment: I upgraded to g++ 4.7, but still same output. I still think this is a misunderstanding of regexes on my part. Too often have I blamed software for my own errors in the past.

Comment: The regex is good. Try escaping > like **\>**, this is just guess. Also the initial .* isn't required just use **>(.+)**

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060025/is-this-c11-regex-error-me-or-the-compiler

Comment: @tuxuday, `>` has no special meaning, but in some flavors `\>` is an end-of-word boundary.  Best to leave it as it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in libstdc++'s implementation. Watch these:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    {
        using namespace std;
        regex my_r("(.*)(6)(.*)");
        smatch m;
        if (regex_match(std::string{"123456789"}, m, my_r)) {
            std::cout << m.length(1) << ", "
                      << m.length(2) << ", "
                      << m.length(3) << std::endl;
        }
    }

    {
        using namespace boost;
        regex my_r("(.*)(6)(.*)");
        smatch m;
        if (regex_match(std::string{"123456789"}, m, my_r)) {
            std::cout << m.length(1) << ", "
                      << m.length(2) << ", "
                      << m.length(3) << std::endl;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you compile with gcc, the first one (libstdc++) returns the totally wrong result **9, -2, 4** and the second one (boost's implementation) returns **5, 1, 3** as expected.

If you compile with clang + libc++, your code works fine.

(Note that libstdc++'s regex implementation is only "partially supported", as described in http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52719.)

Comment: Oh my, that’s singularly annoying. Any chance of choosing another syntax option? Not that I’d *want* something other than ECMA-Script … but if that doesn’t work … (incidentally, I’ve now started wondering why they didn’t go with PCRE).

Comment: By the way, the bug still exists in GCC 4.7.

Comment: thank you for the examples and explanations. I guess it's not fair of me to expect much if it is only partially supported. I'll either use boost or avoid regexes for the time being.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: It's not related to ECMAScript. `regex my_r("(.*)(6)(.*)", regex::extended)` still have the same bug.

Comment: Ah, rats. I thought the *engines* were pluggable but it looks like it’s only the parser.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify your regular expression so that matched parts are divided into groups:

```
std::regex my_r("(.*)>(.*)\\).*"); // group1>group2).*
std::string temp("~(cols=\"64\">Hut)~");
std::sregex_iterator reg_it(temp.begin(), temp.end(), my_r);

if (reg_it->size() > 1) {
    std::cout
        << "1: " << reg_it->str(1) << std::endl  // group1 match
        << "2: " << reg_it->str(2) << std::endl; // group2 match
}
```

outputs:

```
1: ~(cols="64"
2: Hut
```

Note that groups are specified by bracets `( /* your regex here */ )` and if you want to make a bracet part of your expression, then you need to escape it with `\`, which is `\\` in code. For more information see **[Grouping Constructs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx)**.

This question can also help you: [How do I loop through results from std::regex_search?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7301649/1168156)

Also don't use `using namespace std;` at the beginning of your files, it's a bad practice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for your tip regarding `using namespace std;`. I appreciate the explanations!